# Unable to create Android Q emulator

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-studio-3.5

I have been trying to create an Android Q based emulator. The following errors keep on coming. I am on **Android Studio 3.5**

Here are the components so far I've installed[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you getting updates from the stable or canary channel?

Comment: stable channel, I guess

Comment: try switching to canary channel and try to download the update, then later switch back to stable.